# convert string property of list to enum

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums

How can I convert my list Letter string property Size to an enum correctly?

Customer.Letter.Size is type string.

```
Customer.Letter[i].Size = (BusinessObjects.CONSTANTS.E_Letters)BusinessObjects.CONSTANTS.dict[Customer.Letter[i].Size];//i variable declared in an for loop
```

That is my enum:

```
public enum E_Size {
    small = 1,
    medium = 2,
    big = 3
}
```

Here my dictionary:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, E_Size> dict = new Dictionary<string, E_Size> {
        { "small", E_Size.small},
        { "medium", E_Size.medium},
        { "big", E_Size.big}
    };
```

Comment: Looks ok. Where do you have problems?

Comment: getting the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'BusinessObjects.CONSTANTS.E_Size' to 'string'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using standard `Enum.Parse`?

```
  String source = "small"; 
  // E_Size.small 
  E_Size size = (E_Size) (Enum.Parse(typeof(E_Size), source));
```

Reverse conversion (from `E_Size` to `String`) either

```
  E_Size source = E_Size.small;
  String result = source.ToString();
```

or

```
  E_Size source = E_Size.small;
  String result = Enum.GetName(typeof(E_Size), source);
```

Answer (score 1):

convert to string, not to enum:

```
Customer.Letter[i].Size = BusinessObjects.CONSTANTS.dict[Customer.Letter[i].Size].ToString();
```